# Newbie here: ORA-00907 help me identify?

Tags: sql, oracle

```
CREATE TABLE PROJECT(
                      PROJECT_ID           INT PRIMARY KEY,
                      CUSTOMER_ID          INT REFERENCES CUSTOMER(CUSTOMER_ID),
                      PROJECT_DESCRIPTION  VARCHAR(30),
                      PROJECT_DATE         DATE, 
                      ESTIMATED_START_DATE DATE,
                      ESTIMATED_END_DATE
                      ESTIMATED_BUDGET     NUMBER(9,2), 
                      ACTUAL_START_DATE    DATE,
                      ACTUAL_END_DATE      DATE, 
                      ACTUAL_COST          NUMBER(9,2),
                      MANAGER_ID           INT REFERENCES EMPLOYEE(EMPLOYEE_ID)
                    );
```

I am doing an SQL project and I am missing a right parenthesis, I can't actually quite seem to see where I am missing one.

Comment: I've just reformatted the DDL statement, can you see the issue now?

Comment: The above comment is a key to identify such errors, so it would be much simpler to use appropriate formatting when you start writing the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed to provide the data type for the column `ESTIMATED_END_DATE`. It should be something like `ESTIMATED_END_DATE DATE`, similar to `ESTIMATED_START_DATE DATE`. And of course, there is needed a comma after this since further columns follow.